# Text in a button tag doesn't show up as supposed

Tags: css

Not able to change color of the font as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0mwr.png). As you can see, The text "Weiter" doesnt show up as supposed in the button.

I made the font size that big to show, that the word is behind the button and that i cant change the color of it. I tried to avoid that by using !important behind the styles but that actually also didn't work out for me.

I actually don't know how to bring that into a working snippet. Hope that still helps!

```css
.btn--next {
    font-size: 100px;
    color: var(--standard-text) !important;
}
.btn {
    height: 3rem;
    width: 10rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #0645a0 0%, #00d4ff 100%);
    border: none;
    font-family: 'Fjalla One';
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
user agent stylesheet
button {
    appearance: auto;
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: -internal-light-dark(black, white);
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    cursor: default;
    background-color: -internal-light-dark(rgb(239, 239, 239), rgb(59, 59, 59));
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0em;
    font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
    padding: 1px 6px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: outset;
    border-color: -internal-light-dark(rgb(118, 118, 118), rgb(133, 133, 133));
    border-image: initial;
}
.content--task {
    font-size: 1rem;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0645a0 0%, #00d4ff 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    font-family: 'Fjalla One';
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 20rem;
    align-items: center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    height: 12rem;
    width: 20rem;
    border: 5px solid;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0645a0 0%, #00d4ff 100%) 1;
}
:root {
    --standard-background: rgb(36, 35, 35);
    --standard-text: rgb(116, 116, 116);
    --question-text: rgb(51, 135, 204);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Lets give it a sip</title>
    <script src="../js/script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fjalla+One&family=Parisienne&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Parisienne&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="interface interface--characters">
        <h1 class="title title--characters">Lets give it a sip</h1>
        <form class="form form--character" action="game.html">
            <div class="form--inputs">
                <input type="text" class="input input--players" placeholder="Spieler 1"><br>
                <input type="text" class="input input--players" placeholder="Spieler 2"><br>
                <input type="text" class="input input--players" placeholder="Spieler 3"><br>
                <input type="text" class="input input--players" placeholder="Spieler 4"><br>
            </div>
            <br>
            <button class="btn btn--add-characters" type="button">Spieler hinzufügen</button>
            <button class="btn btn--continue" type="button" style="margin-bottom: 2em;">Fortfahren</button>  
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="interface interface--start">
        <fieldset class="container container--rounds">
            <legend class="title title--game">Lets give it a sip</legend>
            
            <div class="content content--round">
            <p class="text text--round">Runde: </p><br>
            <button class="btn btn--start" type="button">Start</button>
            </div>

            <div class="content content--selection">
                <ul class="list list--players"></ul>
            </div>

            <div class="content content--task">
                <h2 class="name name--player"></h2>
                <h4 class="phrase phrase--question"></h4>
                <button class="btn btn--next" type="button">Weiter</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML to the question, preferably in a [runnable snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Just added it. Hope that helps

Comment: [Read this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) on how to edit your question with a runnable example. Key word is _minimal_ - only show us enough to reproduce the problem. Too much code and a lot of people may find it too time-consuming/difficult to help.

Comment: I can't reproduce it in JSFiddle. Looks nothing like the image and the Weiter doesn't even show up. Are you sure this is the right css?

Comment: However, based on the image and your styles, I'm not convinced the word is "behind" the button as you say - the word has the same color as the linear-gradient you've applied to the button. Again, it'll be hard to say properly until we can see it in action as you see it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uk7d1xm4/            Here is the short snippet of it

Comment: @Louisokk what's your expected output?

Comment: The text in front of the button with any other color than the gradient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that all elements within the `div` with a class of `content--task` are inheriting the `-webkit-text-fill-color` property, which is set (twice) to `transparent`:

```css
.content--task {
  /* ... */
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; /* duplicate */
  font-family: 'Fjalla One';
  /* ... */
}
```

Instead of declaring that on `.content--task`, you should place it on specific elements that should get that treatment otherwise you will have to write styles to *undo* it.

Here's what it looks like with the `*-text-fill-color` removed:

```css
/*RESET CSS*/
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--standard-background);
}


/*root*/
:root {
  --standard-background: rgb(36, 35, 35);
  --standard-text: rgb(116, 116, 116);
  --question-text: rgb(51, 135, 204);
}

/* GENERAL CSS */

.interface {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--standard-background);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 12rem;
  width: 20rem;
  border: 5px solid;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0645a0 0%, #00d4ff 100%) 1;
}

.title {
  font-family: 'Parisienne', cursive;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 3rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0645a0 0%, #00d4ff 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.btn {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 10rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #0645a0 0%, #00d4ff 100%);
  border: none;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One';
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.interface--start {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
}

.container--rounds {
  flex-direction: column;
  height: auto;
  width: 20rem;
}

.content--round {
  display: block;
}

.content--task {
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0645a0 0%, #00d4ff 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One';
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 20rem;
  align-items: center;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  /* IE 5.5-7 */
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
  /* Firefox 1.0-2.0 */
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  /* current browsers */
}

.btn--next {
  font-size: 100px;
  color: var(--standard-text) !important;
}

.content--task {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fjalla+One&family=Parisienne&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Parisienne&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="interface interface--start">
  <fieldset class="container container--rounds">
    <legend class="title title--game">Lets give it a sip</legend>

    <div class="content content--task">
      <h2 class="name name--player"></h2>
      <h4 class="phrase phrase--question"></h4>
      <button class="btn btn--next" type="button">Weiter</button>
    </div>

  </fieldset>
</div>
```